# Why can't i use the map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
function App() {
  const state=useMemoState();
  const [btnOn, setBtnOn]=useState(false);

  const colorOnClick=(e)=>{
   const stateFilter=state.map(item=>{
    var a=item.memos.current_memo===item.memos.num
    return a;
   });
   console.log(stateFilter); 
   setBtnOn({
    btnOn:!btnOn,
    ...stateFilter,
    color:e.target.name
   });
  }
return(
<article 
    id="bgColor" 
    className={btnOn? state.filter(item=>item.memos.current_memo===item.memos.num).color : "yellow"
  }>
      
    <div id="color" class="texteditor">
      <div class="colorpicker">
        <button name="black" class="cbtn cbtn-black" onClick={colorOnClick}> <div></div></button>
        <button name="white" class="cbtn cbtn-white" onClick={colorOnClick}><div></div></button>
        <button name="red" class="cbtn cbtn-red" onClick={colorOnClick}><div></div></button>
        <button name="blue" class="cbtn cbtn-blue" onClick={colorOnClick}><div></div></button>
        <button name="yellow" class="cbtn cbtn-yellow" onClick={colorOnClick}><div></div></button>
      </div>
);
}
```

Briefly, I am implementing Notepad and an array called state is in another file.

The code is written so that the background color changes when the button is pressed, so the goal is to find out what the pressed button is and put the name of the button in the color part of it. But the map function is not being used. Is there any other way?

Comment: What does "the map function is not being used" mean? What does the console.log show? What does `state` contain?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot you need to fix on your code before worrying about the `map` call:

1. Your `setBtnOn` function (the function returned by [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)) accepts a single parameter. So your call should be just `setBtnOn(!btnOn)`.
2. Assuming the `state` is an array... The `filter` function returns another array, and your array most likely won't have a `color` attribute. So when you wrote your [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) call, you most like were looking for a [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) call (which returns a single element).
3. You are probably missing some kind of code to update the state.

Fix those issues and then we can try to help you.